# Python, Muilti threads on server, separate fine, together not work

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm working on a python program that works as follows:
there are a server and a client that transfer files by tcp socket, more specifically, the client send file request to server and server send the file back if he has it.
The server also generates new RSA key pairs and named them by the given name (get the name by raw-input), and save the keys to different places.

here's my code of server, I tested the two functions separately, both of them works fine. But when I try to put them together by opening two threads, nothing shows up.

```
import sys
import socket
import os
import threading

def sendKey(func):
    host = ''
    skServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    skServer.bind((host,2525))
    skServer.listen(10)
    print "Server Active"
    bFileFound = 0
    path="/Users/ChunjieXu/Desktop/Publickeys"
    os.chdir(path)

    while True:
        Content,Address = skServer.accept()
        print Address
        sFileName = Content.recv(1024)
        for file in os.listdir(path):
            if file == sFileName:
                bFileFound = 1
                break

        if bFileFound == 0:
            print sFileName+" Not Found On Server"

        else:
            print sFileName+" File Found"
            fUploadFile = open(sFileName,"rb")
            sRead = fUploadFile.read(1024)
            while sRead:
                Content.send(sRead)
                sRead = fUploadFile.read(1024)
            print "Sending Completed"
        break

    Content.close()
    skServer.close()

def genkeys(func):
    while True:
        path="/Users/ChunjieXu/Desktop/Publickeys"
        files=os.listdir(path)

        piname=raw_input('Please enter the Pi Name (5 letters):')

        if piname in files:
            print('Name exists, please enter a new name.')
        else:
            os.chdir('/Users/ChunjieXu/Desktop/Allkeys')
            os.makedirs(piname)
            os.chdir(piname)
            os.system('openssl req -new -x509 -keyout ./cakey.pem -out cacert.pem -days 365')
            os.system('cp cakey.pem cakey.pem.enc')
            os.system('openssl rsa -in ./cakey.pem.enc -out ./cakey.pem')
            os.system('openssl rsa -in ./cakey.pem.enc -passin pass:1234 -pubout -out ./capublickey.pem')
            for old_name in os.listdir('.'):
                prefix=piname
                new_name=prefix+old_name
                os.rename(old_name,new_name)
            for keys in os.listdir('.'):
                result=piname+'capublickey.pem'
                shutil.copy(result,path)


threads=[]
t1=threading.Thread(target=sendKey,)
threads.append(t1)
t2=threading.Thread(target=genkeys,)
threads.append(t2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for t in  threads:
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()
    print 'done'
```

here's my code of client:

```
import sys
import socket 
import os


skClient = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
skClient.connect(("127.0.0.1",2525))

sFileName = raw_input("Enter Filename to download from server : ")
sData = "Temp"
path = "/Users/ChunjieXu/Desktop/Publickeysnode0"
os.chdir(path)

while True:
    skClient.send(sFileName)
    sData = skClient.recv(1024)
    fDownloadFile = open(sFileName,"wb")
    while sData:
        fDownloadFile.write(sData)
        sData = skClient.recv(1024)
    print "Download Completed"
    break

skClient.close()
```

here's the output when I do 'python server.py'

> user$ python server.py
>
> done

I'm new to the thread and not very clear of what's going on there, can anyone please help me with that? Any tips are welcome and appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your program won't wait for your threads to finish. You're starting the threads, then your program is printing "done" and exiting before they have a chance to finish.

To wait for a thread to finish, you should call the [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) method on it.

Here's an example using your main method:

```
threads=[] 
t1=threading.Thread(target=sendKey,)
threads.append(t1)
t2=threading.Thread(target=genkeys,)
threads.append(t2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for t in  threads:
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

     for t in threads:
         t.join()

     print 'done'
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much, I modified that and it worked for the first time, and then if I try to download other files or generate new keys, I got other problems.....

Comment: @jenny徐春杰 Looking at the code you posted, it looks like you have `break` statements at the end of your while loops. When Python executes a `break` statement, it exits out of whatever loop it is currently in, so your program will only run once while those `break` statements are there.

Comment: @jenny徐春杰 Also, `os.makedirs` will throw an `OSError` if you try to create a directory that already exists.